# Android Studio scrollbar in gridview

Tags: android, kotlin, button, gridview, scrollbar

When my gridview is too long, so it exceeds the length of the screen, it dissapears in the bottom and there is no scrollbar. The elements are added in the kotlin file which are connected through firebase where they are saved

fragment_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/activeTicketSearchViewID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="Search Here"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" /><!-- set query string of an search view -->

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addTicketButtonID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="#ff8aa9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/add_ticket"
        />


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/mainActiveTicketGridViewID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activeTicketSearchViewID" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the MainActivity.kt (partially):

```
    fun addArchivedTicketsToGridFromDB(grid: GridView) {
        println("loading archived tickets...")
        if (!isSignedIn) {
            return
        }
        mainArchivedGrid = grid
        firebaseService.getPageTicketsSortedDate(10, TicketStatus.ARCHIVED).addOnCompleteListener() { result ->
            println("result: $result")
            if (result.isSuccessful) {
                ArchivedTicketscourseList.clear()
                val tickets = result.result?.documents?.map { document ->
                    val ticket = document.toObject(Ticket::class.java)
                    ticket
                }
                println("tickets: $tickets")
                for (ticket in tickets!!) {
                    val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy")
                    val buttonText = "${Helpers.addEllipsisIfTooLong(ticket!!.name, 32)}\n\n${format.format(ticket.date)}"
                    ArchivedTicketscourseList.add(CourseModel(buttonText))
                }
                val adapter = CourseGVAdapter(this, ArchivedTicketscourseList)
                mainArchivedGrid.adapter = adapter
            } else {
                println("error: ${result.exception}")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't load Tickets", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

i've tried adding `android:scrollbars="vertical"` and tried setting `android:layout_heigt` to `wrap_content` but no success.